# Zee Chapter VII.5: Can the fermion $10$ be the composite of fermion $5^*$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, representation-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

In Zee Chapter VII.5 QFT book:

He showed that the standard model fermions form $5^*$ and $10$ representations of $SU(5)$:
$$
5^* \oplus 10.
$$
In particular, the $10$ is the anti-symmetric matrix representation from the tensor product of $5 \otimes 5 $:
$$5 \otimes 5 = 10 \oplus 15$$
or
$$(5 \otimes 5)_A = 10  $$

Question

1. If the fermion representation $10$ is from the anti-symmetric  part of $5 \otimes 5$, can the fermion $10$ be the composite of fermion $5^*$?

In Zee's notation, can we regard the fermion $10$ (the left-handed up and down quark doublet, the right handed $u$ quark, the right-handed electron) as the bound state of some sort of two $5$ (each $5$ forms the left-handed neutrino and electron doublet, the right handed $d$ quark):
$$
\psi^{\mu\nu} = (\psi^{*\mu}\psi^{*\nu}-\psi^{*\nu}\psi^{*\mu})^*?
$$

2. How does the fermion statistics match on the left and right handed sides?

Comment: The representations may compose as you observe, but the spins and fermion numbers cannot. Observing a representation theory coincidence will not generate a new physics model.

Comment: did people try this: can one add new fermions into the model to match the fermi statistics?

Comment: I don’t know, alas…

Comment: Someone did it earlier this month. https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.02464

Comment: thanks so much for this (ref)